# mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou com um problema aqui com Mysql, está dando erros, já fiz todo tipo de alteração. Já tentei mudar a função Mysql para Mysqli e só aumentam erros.

Código:

```
<?php
   $sql["host"] = "localhost";
    $sql["usuario"] = "root";
    $sql["senha"] = "arfito";
    $sql["base"] = "digify";
    $conexao = mysql_connect($sql["host"],$sql["usuario"],$sql["senha"]);
    $select_database = mysql_select_db($sql["base"], $conexao);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
?>
```

e da o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/public_html/includes/config.php:6 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/public_html/index.php(7): include() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/public_html/includes/config.php on line 6

Quando mudo de Mysql para Mysqli da o seguinte erro:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /var/www/public_html/includes/config.php on line 7
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/public_html/includes/config.php on line 8

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_array() in /var/www/public_html/index.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/public_html/index.php on line 9
```

A linha #9 do código do Index.php:

```
$web = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"));
```

Comment: mysql* não existe a partir da versão 7 do php logo tem mesmo de utilizar mysqli. Mostre qual o código que utilizou para a versão mysqli. Lembro que `mysqli_query` leva como primeiro parâmetro a ligação

Comment: Eu só tenho esse código a cima, não sou muito bom com mysqli. Achei que so fosse necessario mudar o mysql para mysqli.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repare no erro que lhe dá para a função `mysql_connect`:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect() ....

Isto é porque no ambiente que está a executar ela nem sequer existe. Quando olhamos para a [documentação dessa função](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) vemos que ela foi removida a partir da versão PHP 7.0.0:

> **Warning** This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed
>   in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used (...)

A própria documentação lhe indica que deve trocar para *MySQLi* ou *PDO*. Se tem uma versão PHP 7 ou maior tem mesmo de trocar.

O seu código com *MySQLi* ficaria assim:

```
$sql["host"] = "localhost";
$sql["usuario"] = "root";
$sql["senha"] = "arfito";
$sql["base"] = "digify";

//a conexão agora passa a levar a base de dados com quarto parâmetro
$conexao = mysqli_connect($sql["host"],$sql["usuario"],$sql["senha"], $sql["base"]);

mysqli_query($conexao, "SET NAMES utf8");
//--------------^ conexão é agora o 1º parametro do mysqli_query

$web = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM settings ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"));
//--------------------------------------^ conexão é agora o 1º parametro do mysqli_query
```

O `mysql_fetch_array` passou para `mysqli_fecth_array`, e o `mysql_query` passou para `mysqli_query` mas também tem de levar como primeiro parâmetro a ligação

Documentação para o [`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php) e para o [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Obrigado, Funcionou. Fizeste o meu dia, passei noites sem dormir a lutar com isso. Obrigado @Isac

Comment: @AbdArfeAmadeDomingos De nada, fico contente por ter ajudado

Comment: Obrigado mesmo. Deus abençoe.

Answer (score 3):

Correção para mysqli:

```
$sql["host"] = "localhost";
$sql["usuario"] = "root";
$sql["senha"] = "arfito";
$sql["base"] = "digify";
$conexao = mysqli_connect($sql["host"],$sql["usuario"],$sql["senha"]);
$select_database = mysqli_select_db($conexao, $sql["base"]);
mysqli_query($conexao, "SET NAMES utf8");
```

Links uteis:

[mysqli_select_db](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.select-db.php)

[mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou.